# Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache does not load CSS or javascript

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, apache2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to insert a new website in a digital ocean server. There are currently 4 websites being hosted there in Nginx. I've created a Nginx Virtual Host that works as a reverse proxy for Apache, which is listening in the port 8000. It is currently redirecting when I try to access the domain, but it is failing to load all the CSS and Javascript. It just loads the HTML. But if I access it through www.domain.com:8000 it loads perfectly.

The Nginx configuration file for the website:

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com; 

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;

#   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

#   location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
#        expires 1s;
#   }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }
    location ~ \.js {
       add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}

    location ~ \.html$ {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;       
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8000;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

The Apache .conf file:

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>

ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I don't use PHP on the website, just HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: You are only proxying HTML to apache